# How to take the Laplace transform of 1/f(t)?

Tags: laplace-transform

I know I am streching it... But still: Is there any general property of the Laplace transform of 1/f(t)? 
For example, one general property of a Laplace transform, from t-->s, is that

```
LT[t^nf(t)]=(-1)^nF^(n)(s)
```

What can we say in the same spirit about LT[1/f(t)]?

Thanks.

Comment: Consider $f(t)=t$. Then $$Lf(t) = \int_0^\infty te^{-st}\ \mathsf dt = \frac1{s^2},$$ but 
$$
\int_0^\infty \frac1t e^{-st}\ \mathsf dt
$$
does not converge, so $L(1/f)(t)$ is not defined.